# Issue with "overflow: auto" on element inside fluid flexbox container in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

**Task:**

There is a box with fluid height that has to be centered in the browser window. It consists of three parts:
- top part with any length depending on text inside
- bottom part with any length depending on text indside
- middle part that is scrollable if there is not enough space to fit the text

**Problem:**
Implemeting the task I'm using flexbox on the parent `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`. Top and bottom parts are having `flex-shrink: 0;`
The part in the middle is set to `overlow: auto`. And for some reason there is no scroll in Internet Explorer 11. Overflow property is completely ignored. In Firefox and Chrome it works fine.

**Screenshots:**

Chrome/Firefox:

[image]

Internet explorer 11:

[image]

**Code:**

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;    
}

.scrollable {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top">I'm any length text</div>
    <div class="scrollable">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lacinia eleifend nisi ac laoreet. Praesent commodo bibendum turpis nec finibus. Aenean ac tincidunt velit. Sed et sodales quam, efficitur viverra erat. Pellentesque aliquet ultrices lectus at vulputate. In pulvinar nec ex sed condimentum. Vivamus vitae vulputate urna. Aliquam lobortis iaculis lacus a dictum. Pellentesque odio mauris, tincidunt sit amet sem dapibus, pretium ornare turpis. In sit amet justo luctus, ultricies nisi eu, iaculis erat. Pellentesque et tempor nibh. Vivamus congue elementum elit, id tempus dolor laoreet sed.

Vestibulum dictum efficitur metus, in consectetur turpis. Vestibulum vel vehicula ante. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc congue, odio ac malesuada pharetra, velit nisl facilisis lorem, at tincidunt ex metus volutpat diam. Integer varius dolor at tellus dapibus ultrices. Nulla sagittis purus in mauris vestibulum, ac facilisis turpis condimentum. Ut mattis in ex eu mattis. Nullam ac elit metus. Nullam finibus tempus lacus, sit amet sagittis ante. Morbi sit amet sem a nisi volutpat luctus. Suspendisse eget condimentum dui. Proin suscipit sed sapien a efficitur.      
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">I'm any length footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any idea how to fix this issue? What's wrong there and how to make IE renders scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has quite some bugs, and ignoring `min/max-height` is one of them.

In this case I found using flex *column* direction on the `wrapper`, and remove `align-items: center` does the trick.

To make it aligned horizontally centered, use auto margin on the `box`

*Note, there is still one flaw with this in IE, if you start and manually change the browser height, the scroll won't disappear even if the text would fit, but if to reload the page, it works. Am still looking into this, to see what/if can be done to get rid of that issue.*

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;    
}

.scrollable {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top">I'm any length text</div>
    <div class="scrollable">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lacinia eleifend nisi ac laoreet. Praesent commodo bibendum turpis nec finibus. Aenean ac tincidunt velit. Sed et sodales quam, efficitur viverra erat. Pellentesque aliquet ultrices lectus at vulputate. In pulvinar nec ex sed condimentum. Vivamus vitae vulputate urna. Aliquam lobortis iaculis lacus a dictum. Pellentesque odio mauris, tincidunt sit amet sem dapibus, pretium ornare turpis. In sit amet justo luctus, ultricies nisi eu, iaculis erat. Pellentesque et tempor nibh. Vivamus congue elementum elit, id tempus dolor laoreet sed.
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">I'm any length footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;` on the element